# Triggering the "stack" option manually on a JQuery UI draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, javascript

I have a quick question about the draggable in JQuery UI. I can set DIVs as draggable and set the "stack" option on the draggable. The stack option makes the DIV that is being dragged automatically come to the front.

However, I would like to invoke this functionality manually. I would like to programmatically invoke the draggable's stack function and bring it to the front. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay--couldn't you just increase the z-index for the element you want to pop to the front? I believe that's all that jQueryUI is doing.

Comment: No, I've already done that and it works fine. I want to know how to "trigger" the stack function that brings the div to the front. I want to do it manually without having to wait for the drag event to do it for me.

Comment: @Chevex: Okay--couldn't you just increase the z-index for the element you want to pop to the front?  I believe that's all that jQueryUI is doing.